# Pov-ray Summing scenes with separate light sources vs rendering all together

Tags: shadow

I have a scene like two street lights (area lights) illuminating a flag pole  in between them. If I render the scene once for each scene and sum the result, I get less contrast in each shadow than if I render the scene with both lights on together. I export the scenes as 16bit PNG. The signal is <1 everywhere with both lights on, and I don't normalize. Background is set to black.

Should summing the scenes with separate light sources give same result as rendering the scene once with both light sources? I have set Display_Gamma=1.0 and assumed_gamma 1.0

Some info on the scene (I can post an example pov ray file necessary):

The floor material is:
 pigment { color rgbft<1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0>  }
  finish {ambient 0 diffuse albedo 1.}

The flag pole is:
  texture { pigment {color Black }}

The light sources are like:
    color rgb<0.125,0.125,0.125> 
    area_light <5, 0, 0>, <0, 0, 5>, 5, 5
    adaptive 5
    circular

Answer (score 0):

OK, I also had to set File_Gamma=1.0 
So to keep linear intensity units throughout, set the global option: assumed_gamma 1.0   and in the rendering command, include the parameters:  File_Gamma=1.0  and Display_Gamma=1.0

All three gammas need to be 1.0  if you want to measure shadow contrast in linear units.